People can not view the document they uploaded in SharePoint
What I did is I created a list in SharePoint, and in the settings of the list, I made so that only the person who created it or people who edited can view that item in the list.
Then I created a flow using PowerAutomate and I used the action "Grant access":

Now they are able to view that item and can edit too.
And when I've checked their permission level in SharePoint for that item, it shows that they can indeed edit the item and view documents, but they can not view any document what so ever and the site tell them that they do not have permission to view the documents.

What i found is when you use the "Grant Access" action in PowerAutomate is that the permison level is not exactly like the permison in SharePoint,So i hade to use anothr level of permisons for the doucment to work, but because the Grant Access have only two options which are: View and Edit. I hade to use a custom one
so i user the

role:1073741828


so people can view the files
these are the diffrent code for each level

